# Django JSON not being saved in sqlite database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am just testing some stuff to figure out how Django works in general.

Now I have these small code chunks here which are giving me some problems.

Here is a chunk of my `models.py` file

```
class Recipes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    style = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    brewer = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='All Grain')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='1')
    batch_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_size = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, default=0.0)
    boil_time = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    efficiency = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=75.0)
    ibu = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    abv = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    notes = models.TextField(default='')
    carbonation = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=4, default=0.0)
    primary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    secondary_age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    age = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=1, max_digits=4, default = 0)
    __fermentables = []
  
    @classmethod
    def create(cls,attr):
        recipe = cls()
        # do something with the book
        for k in Recipes._meta.fields:
            if  k.name in attr:
                setattr(recipe,k.name,attr[k.name])
        return recipe
```

Here is the part of `views.py` which is giving me trouble

```
def saveRecipe(request):
        try:
            data=json.loads(request.read())
            print("printing values")
            print(data["name"])  #prints here works
            recipe = Recipes.create(attr=data)
            recipe.name = data["name"]
            recipe.save()
            recipe.addYeast(items=data["yeast"])
            recipe.addFermentables(items=data["fermentables"])
            recipe.addHops(items=data["hops"])
            recipe.addMashStep(items=data["mash"])
            return  HttpResponse(serialize('json', [recipe]),  content_type='application/json')
        except:
           
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

Basically I have a button which parses JSON from filled forms and when I print name `print(data["name"])` it seems to be parsed correctly.

Now I for testing purposes I put `recipe.save()` in the part of the views file where you can see and I think that it is technically supposed to save the parsed information into the database but when I check the database there is nothing there.

So basically my question is why is the `recipe.save()`   not doing what it's supposed to and what is missing in order to save the data correctly?

For the purpose of simplicity let's ignore everything that comes after the save fuction.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to write your own create method. You could use `Recipes.objects.create`.

You must be getting an error because of pub_date couldn't be empty. While you are working/debugging commentin the try-except blocks. So you could handle the error.

Comment: But Im not getting any errors :/ I simply press the save button and when I check the database there is nothing there. Or could this also be because of this?

Comment: Did you try it without the `try-except` block?

Comment: Haven't yet. Gonna try it. But I think that I need to have it in this case. Dont I?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use it. But while some things don't work. You need to disable and debug where is the error. Otherwise, you could not see the exceptions. After you think all works as wanted, put them back.